# Split dataset in train and set validation. Why this error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have to split my dataset into train and set validation (70 and 30%)
I used this code:

```
def get_train_test(df, y_col, x_cols, ratio):
""" 
This method transforms a dataframe into a train and test set, for this you need to specify:
1. the ratio train : test (usually 0.7)
2. the column with the Y_values
"""
mask = np.random.rand(len(df)) &lt; ratio
df_train = df[mask]
df_test = df[~mask]

Y_train = df_train[y_col].values
Y_test = df_test[y_col].values
X_train = df_train[x_cols].values
X_test = df_test[x_cols].values
return df_train, df_test, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test

y_col_glass = 'Type'
x_cols_glass = list(df_glass.columns.values)
x_cols_glass.remove(y_col_glass)

train_test_ratio = 0.7
df_train, df_test, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = get_train_test(df_glass, y_col_glass, x_cols_glass, train_test_ratio)
```

but I have error on y_col_glass and ratio.
Please help!
This is the error

```
 File "/Users/blabla/.py", line 120, in <module>
    x_cols_glass.remove(y_col_glass)
   line 1576, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: Why don't you use sklearn split function instead of rewriting your less efficient one?

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @Matthieu Brucher, you can use the sklearn split test/train function:
http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html